# How to get related fields in another model from current model, using datamapper in CI?

Tags: codeigniter, one-to-many, codeigniter-datamapper

I am a newbie user to CodeIgniter and DataMapper. I have a User model and User Group model. Both of this model has an one-to-many relationships. Is there any way I could get user_group_name in User Group using the User model?

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading the Datamapper user guide, on http://datamapper.exitecms.org.

You can include columns from a related model into the result by using include_related().

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with codeigniter first.

As for your question, I think it would be better for you to get help from the datamapper forums or the codeigniter forums.

Answer (score 0):

Wanwizard and Thorpe,
Thanx for both of you. I have got the solution. I only call Group model from User model. The following code would explain it.

```
<?php 
    foreach($users->all as $user)
    {
        $user->group->get();
    }
?>
```